# How to use unconventional texture format

Tags: textures, directx11, hlsl, format

I would like to use a texture that could have more than 4 channels.

I have seen a post where they use a single channel R8 texture to store string chars.
I'm thinking of using something like that with width = TextureSizeX * n where n is my number of channel and texturesizeX the size of the screen for instance.

Then I'm planning to use texture.load instruction to get the data. In the case of data stored in 5 bytes channels (e.g. RGBAX), I'm considering Input.texCoord.x * 5 * ScreenSize + (0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4) as UV coord x parameter to recover the 5 data sequentially. Will this work?

I have also seen that we can use RWByteAddressBuffer that has load, load2 load3 and load4 functions. Will it be better? The idea here is that for my 5 bytes channel I could use load3 to have part of the data as uint3 and load2 for the rest as uint2 that will be ok for my needs.

This is for Directx11 HLSL SM5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my procedure for using multiple subcolor in one resource.

Why this : to create 4 layers of data (color, normal, depth) for a deferred lighting to be used in a screen space reflection pipeline when having only 8 rendertargets available.

1 ) Create resources compatible for being used as either UAV/SRV/RTV.
Given a screen size of SCREENX and SCREENY, create the three resources with SCREENX*4 size as we will store 4 interleaved data in the X axis.

Color as RGBA8 used as UAV/RTV (and SRV in SSR)

Normal as RG8 used as UAV/SRV (I’m using viewspace normal so Z is always negative and calculated back with NZ = srqt(dot(NXY,NXY))-1;

Depth R16 in my demo. Used as UAV/SRV

2 Generating the layers

Clear everything

OMSetRenderTargetAndUnorderedAccessViews(0,NULL,DepthStencil, 0, 3, UAVs, 0);//Note use of regular Depthstencil buffer for using [earlydepthstencil] in the PS.

Render the scene

In the shader
Set the three UAV as resources to be modified in u0, u1, u2

In the ps shader I’ musing a selective UAV write to draw an object if it is visible in the corresponding layer. This is in a mesh buffer constant as float4 Vislay.x-w for layers 0-3. Vislay.x is always 1 in fact.

```
 float4 Color = calculate the pixel color;
 float3 Normal = calculate your normal;
 float Depth = input.pos.z;
 float2 uUV = Input.Pos.xy*float2(4,1);//get screen coordinate where to write for the first subdata. Remember we have 4 subdata to write so multiply x by 4.
```

In my app the first layer contains all objects, the other layers only objects visible in these layers if they are occluded once, twice or more than twice (stored in Vislay). So it is the same color as the whole image that will go to the selected layer (if any).

```
uavColorRGBA[uUV] = Color;
uavNormalRG[uUV] = Normal.rg;
uavDepthR[uUV] = Depth;
uUV.x++;
if ( VisLay.y ) 
{
    uavColorRGBA[uUV] = Color;
    uavNormalRG[uUV] = Normal.xy;
    uavDepthR[uUV] = Depth;
}
uUV.x++;
if ( VisLay.z ) 
{
    uavColorRGBA[uUV] = Color;
    uavNormalRG[uUV] = Normal.xy;
    uavDepthR[uUV] = Depth;
}
uUV.x++;
if ( VisLay.w ) 
{
    uavColorRGBA[uUV] = Color;
    uavNormalRG[uUV] = Normal.xy;
    uavDepthR[uUV] = Depth;
}
```

NOTE : you can do some depth peeling by changing the if ( Vislay ) statements ) by if ( Depth>X)&&(Depth<=Y) where X and Y are the limit of the current min and max Depth you want in the current layer. I have tested this as well. The problem is for objects too close to each other where my first method do better and is independant of depth of objects.

3 The lighting pass

Set the UAV color as regular rendertarget.
Set the Normal and Depth UAVs as SRVs for the pixel shader.

```
OMSetRenderTargets(1, &uavColorRGBAasRTV, NULL);
PSSetShaderResources(4, 1, & uavNormalRGasSRV);//slot 4 and 8 in my app
PSSetShaderResources(8, 1, & uavDepthRasSRV);
```

Set the viewport to be SCREENX*4 instead of SCREENX.

Render to a screen quad

Restore normal viewport if needed.

In the pixel shader, use a regular deferred lighting process. Here I’m combining the outputted light color (with shadows) with the target color in the blending stage.

```
float4 PS_PostDeferred(PS_INPUTQUAD Input) : SV_TARGET0
{
  float2 uUV = Input.Tex.xy*float2(SM_SCREENX4,SM_SCREENY);
  float Depth = txDepthR.Load(uint3(uUV,0)).r;
  if ( Depth==1) return float4(1,1,1,1);
  float3 Normal = txNormal0.Load(uint3(uUV, 0)).rgg;
  return GetLColor(Depth, Input.Tex, Normal);//Normal.xy to xyz in the GetLColor function
}
```

The whole result is below. Upper panels are : colors in the 4 layers, then normals, then normal for the plane to use for SSR (same 4 views), ZBuffer (same 4 views) , Depth in layers as R, G, B and white colors.

[image]

All this works fine but I have to admit that it is slower than regular rendertargets with the use of UAV having an intrinsic performance cost. Maybe someone will have a clever idea to exploit some UAV store instruction I'm not used of.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy will work, but is somewhat inefficient.

Each texture sample has some overhead, so you generally want each one to do as much work for you as it can. Using 5 samples to get 5 numbers gives us the least return on investment we can get. The `RWByteAddressBuffer` does better in terms of samples, but you lose benefits of texture sampling like filtering or reading from compressed formats, and I don't know if its caching performance differs.

I suspect you'll see better performance if you instead split this logical 5-channel texture into two stored textures: one RGB and one RG, both with the actual native dimensions you want (no 5x + i adjustment). Then you sample each one once (2 samples total) to get your 5 numbers, using the most simple addressing pattern that GPUs have been optimized to serve. This cuts down the number of sample requests (and the number of texture cache entries) by half. You can scale this up to 8 channels if you up the two textures to RGBA, and beyond by adding a third texture, etc.

Doing it this way also means that you can use built-in texture filtering or texture compression, if applicable to your use case. For instance, if two of your values are quite correlated or need lower precision than the other 3, you can store them in the RG texture in a compressed format to make more efficient use of the available video memory and texture bandwidth.

A good comparison here is G-buffers used for deferred shading, which also use this "multiple textures" approach rather than interleaving the extra channels in consecutive indices of a wider texture or byte buffer. It's easier to render into this format if you need to update the contents of the super-channel textures dynamically, while the interleaved formats need some more exotic solutions.

As always, the best way to know what performs best for your situation is to build a test and profile it. Something that's "usually faster" can still be slower for a specific situation because it's depending on a resource that's already over-taxed by something else in your scene - it all depends where your bottlenecks are, so profile to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have it working as 3 consecutive RG (2 for RGBA and 1 for XY normal) so the read/write are reduced compared to just R but I agree it will not compete with direct read/write RGB+RG I'm already doing. The idea was to bypass the 8 RTV limit I have. I will go on and see the final result which is effectively for deferred rendering.

Comment: Should I mention I'm filling the texture as UAV. I don't need specific filtering.

Comment: Yes, mentioning the context is usually helpful to include in the question.

Comment: Finally my 4 layers (reason for saving RTV) SSR pipeline works fine with this idea, although the lighting is currently in forward mode. Effectively it is slowwer (>40 FPS) compared to the same with regular RTVs (50FPS) 1920*1080 screen size. My "optimized" 8 RTV use for full 4 layers deferred lighting and SSR is 40 FPS. So this idea for full deferred will probably be less interesting.